# PHP DOMDocument getElementsByTagName return raw XML

Tags: php, domdocument

Is the **getElementsByTagName** function capable of returning the children as a XML blob?

Comment: It returns a node list - not sure what you want when you say an 'XML blob'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) return a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) instance. You can iterate through the [`DOMNode`s](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) contained in it, using [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) to keep concatenating the raw XML to a string.

```
<?php
$a = '<root>
    <prueba>
        <testtag value="1"/>
    </prueba>
    <notprueba>
        <testtag value="1"/>
    </notprueba>
    <prueba>
        <testtag value="2"/>
    </prueba>
</root>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($a);
$x = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("prueba");
$xml = "";
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $xml .= $doc->saveXML($node);
}
var_dump(htmlentities($xml));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FqMoM)